# JavaScript inserting images using string variable as their URL

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm using JavaScript to parse a XML file. One of the XML's attribute is an URL which links to an image. eg. http://localhost/pic.jpg

As the parsing goes on, I use an variable to hold each URL(which is a string variable) and hoping that I can show these images in a table.

The following is part of my code:

```js
for(i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
{
   // looping through the XML file
   var Logo1 = row[i].getElementsByTagName("Logo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   //Logo1 is the string which is a URL
   document.write("<img src= 'Logo1' width='256' height='128'>");
}
```

I use Chrome, but the images won't load....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU6TF.png)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Logo1` is a variable containing an image path (URL, as you say), you need to build the `img` tag in a way that includes the path:

```
document.write('<img src="' + Logo1 + '" width="256" height="128">');
```

This concatenates the `Logo1` string variable into the rest of the tag.

That said, `document.write` is probably not going to work for you in the long run. you would instead create a new `Image` object and set its `src` property:

```
var testImage = new Image();
testImage.src = Logo1;
// add testImage to the DOM
```